# Visa questions: I am currently working in France and going to join Germany soon

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, indian-citizens

I am an Indian with a residence talent permit of France valid till Sep end 2021. I am currently in France. I have a job offer from Germany starting Sep 1, 2021. My questions are :

1. Do I need to go back to India and apply for German Visa from there ?
2. If I can apply from inside France, then what will happen to my French residence permit, provided Germany issues me a VISA ? Isn't it a situation where I have a visa from Germany and a residence permit of France ?
3. Where may I find official information about this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to go back to India and apply for German Visa from there ?

No. As long as you have a legal residence in France, you can apply for a visa at [the German Embassy in France](https://allemagneenfrance.diplo.de/fr-fr/service-consulaire/visa-seite/visa-sejour-longue-duree-seite/visa-de-travail-seite).

> Les citoyens d’Australie, du Canada, des États-Unis d’Amérique, d’Israël, du Japon, de Nouvelle-Zélande, de la République de Corée et du Royaume-Uni de Grande-Bretagne et d’Irlande du Nord ont la possibilité d’obtenir leur titre de séjour obligatoire après leur entrée sur le territoire allemand. **Tous les ressortissants d’autres pays résidant en France doivent en revanche faire une demande de visa long séjour à l’ambassade d’Allemagne à Paris avant d’entrer sur le territoire allemand.**

> If I can apply from inside France, then what will happen to my French residence permit, provided Germany issues me a VISA ? Isn't it a situation where I have a visa from Germany and a residence permit of France ?

They are independent events. Nothing in general prohibits you from possessing multiple visas or residence permits from different countries. Of course, conditions apply to your French residence permit. When you actually move away from France and intend to do so definitively, the residence permit may cease to be valid.

> Where may I find official information about this situation ?

The [German Embassy in France](https://allemagneenfrance.diplo.de/fr-fr/service-consulaire/visa-seite/visa-sejour-longue-duree-seite/visa-de-travail-seite) will provide you with the most up to date information.